Do accidentals have other meanings, or is their usage in this hymn all wrong?
A Setup for This Question: the 99%
I’m pretty sure that a handful of rules covers 99% of the usage of accidentals, especially in notation from the last hundred or more years. Let’s say 95% of their appearance is typical: sharp raises, flat lowers, natural cancels. Another 4% depends on context: parentheses around them means it’s a “courtesy,” meant to remind us; others show up despite being part of the key signature, meant to reinforce the intent of its inclusion where it might be interpreted ambiguously; and so on.
An Example: the 1% That Could Be Confusing but Can Be Inferred
Let’s look at the Darmstadt Gesangbuch (this version apparently from 1728).

The F major key signature is easy enough to understand, but the sharp appears to behave like how we use a natural today in the second-to-last phrase. The note would not be B-flat or B-sharp but B-natural.
The Question: What on Earth is Intended by This Next One Here?
Now, here are two versions of one of those Southern Harmony / Sacred Harp / fuguing tune / American folk style hymns, labeled as “America” (no, not the “My Country ’Tis of Thee” tune). The first is from The Sacred Harp, and the second is from The American Vocalist:


What is going on with the sharps in the second picture? One of them is almost obvious in its intent in making the dominant chord major instead of minor. But what on earth is going on with the rest of them? Why are the F’s and F-sharps clashing all over the place?
Are these accidentals indicating something other than what I expected (raising the pitch)? Or am I reading this incorrectly somehow? Or did the editor just meticulously put all these accidentals in the wrong place? Or was there some strange aesthetic choice of harmony during this time period that I’m unaware of?


Or was there some strange aesthetic choice of harmony during this time period that I’m unaware of?

Yes.  It arises from rules of counterpoint in the Renaissance that sometimes, particularly in the English Renaissance, resulted in both a raised and lowered seventh degree at cadences.  One part has the seventh degree as the lower neighbor of the tonic while another has a descending figure, requiring it to be minor rather than major.  You can find examples of this with some regularity in the music of Thomas Tallis and his contemporaries; I've also encountered such a cadence in an Iberian piece of roughly the same period, but unfortunately I do not remember the title nor the composer.
Apparently this taste persisted to some degree.  The first and third instances in the example shown in the question have the canonical 8-♯7-8 and 5-♭7-5 pattern.  The other examples can be explained by the fact that these pieces were not written in a strict contrapuntal style.

Interesting idea. I hadn’t considered such an old technique (or idiom?) to be in play (the “false relation”). I’m not 100% convinced, but I’m convinced enough to upvote and accept. It just seems weird that some versions don’t have any accidentals and sound much closer to what I expect late 18th, early 19th-C. rural American folk / congregational singing to sound like. And then there’s this one, which we’re speculating hearkens back a few hundred years with English cadences. I think the Vocalist editor must have been conflicted. :-)

They thought more ‘horizontally’ back then — giving more priority to how each line would sound in isolation, and less to the ‘vertical’ of how all parts sound together at any given moment.  This approach remained mainstream in part-writing to some degree until at least the late Baroque (e.g. some Bach preludes and fugues have many moments that sound odd in isolation but make sense when you consider the flow of each part) — and as you say, even longer in some traditions.

That makes sense for the more obviously polyphonic section, but that still leaves me scratching my head at the homophonic section of the beginning. Do you suppose even there it’s still considered “horizontal” thinking?

I will add more later, but I think the first example is more a case of you confusing figured-bass notation with accidentals.  Notice that they're above the bass staff.
The 4-3 indicates a suspension that would be played in an inner voice (not notated), the 6 indicates a first-inversion chord, and the sharps above the lower staff indicate a raised third to form a major triad. The flat above the lower staff indicates a lowered third, in this case a minor triad.
This is entirely different than the second examples, which other answers describe well already.

I understand the figured bass notation. I was trying to present it as an example of an uncommon (by today’s standards) use of the accidental — namely, using a sharp to indicate that the normally flatted note should be natural. I did so, wondering if maybe this hymnal editor had some similar intention with his accidentals, and some answerer here immediately recognized that as the case, but I’m starting to doubt the likelihood. They might just be regular ol’ sharps… which leaves me scratching my head at their placement.

Playing organ, I see sharp more often to indicate flatted note to be natural instead of natural sign. It is more convenient for players instead of using natural sign. Sharp means major triad and flat means minor triad no matter what the key signature is. And because the figured bass symboles are not standartised, I see this use really often now.

The answer is reflected in the notes we associate with the minor scales. Any minor key signature is the same as that of the relative major - F>Dm, B♭>Gm, C>Am, etc.
The scales themselves (sets of notes in common use) are as follows:
Natural minor, with exactly the same notes as the relative major.
Harmonic minor, with the same again, except a raised leading note, making the transition from that to root above sound 'more convincing'.
Melodic minor, which uses the same notes as the natural minor descending, but all notes from the parallel major, bar the m3, ascending. This gives an opportunity to use all of those notes in pieces, and as they're not included in the key signature, must be accompanied by the obligatory accidentals, as found in the examples in the OP.
There will, of course, also be times when V/V and other secondary dominants make their way into the music. Again, those notes need signifying with accidentals.

I’m familiar with how scales are constructed. This is more a why question than a how, but I can put it in similar terms that you raise here: why did one version of the tune use only natural minor and thereby have the independent voices sound consistently consonant whenever their melodies overlapped, but the other version introduce accidentals occasionally and thereby cause some strikingly unpleasant and out-of-place sounding dissonance whenever their melodies overlapped? For this time period and in this context, it seemed very strange to me.
